# How do I rank equally on mobile & desktop?

Tags: seo, ranking, local-seo

I have a site that ranks #1 on Google for a specific keyword on mobile.

On desktop, it ranks #3.

What are the likely considerations I need to be aware of to try and bump up my desktop ranking?

Thanks for any insight.

Joe

Comment: I kinda feel this is a bit too broad? Your search on mobile could simply be more _localised_ for instance?

Comment: Sorry but too broad and we have a catch-all for such questions.

Comment: @SimonHayter mobile & desktop ranking may differ for valid reasons (please check my answer). This is neither the duplicate of the marked question, nor very broad, IMHO. Although the question details can be edited a bit to make it more specific to the title. Is it possible to reopen it? I think more answers to this question will add value to this site.

Comment: The question linked is broad and supports all platforms, if you can't find relevant answers its because no one has left one yet. We have ways of improving old questions and getting new insight through bounties.

Answer (score 1):

[Google is known](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/02/finding-more-mobile-friendly-search.html) to vary search results in mobile & desktop. There may be many reasons why this can happen & most of these are not in your control. Some examples are:

1. May be it's based on location - it's possible that mobile search is revealing more specific location information compared to desktop. So SERP ranking may be varying based on that.
2. May be it's based on optimization - perhaps your page is more optimized
   for mobile compared to the other two sites that top you on desktop. **This is actually a good thing for you**. Or may be it's the opposite, i.e. your site is optimized for mobile experience, but not so much for desktop experience, in that case you may try to improve on that.
3. May be it's based on CTR - Google neither admitted nor denier that Click Through Rate (CTR) is a ranking factor. Either way, Google search algorithms learn based on performance & user's preference to search results are known to vary between mobile and desktop.
4. May be it's based on content - sometimes sites vary content based on the device, screen size etc. and even a minor variation may produce different ranking for highly competitive searches.
5. May be it's based on personalization - on mobile you are identified more easily than desktop, so it's possible that your mobile ranking is based on personalization.

**What can you do?** - Keep working on page optimization, especially work on user experience (UX), perhaps on desktop your main content is not above the fold, [optimize for that](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/PrioritizeVisibleContent), try to gain more backlink naturally (organically), show more authority on the relevant content - i.e. follow the modern SEO best practices. Other than that there's not much you can do.

Comment: What do you mean by "#5 ...mobile ranking is based on personalization."? Why would someone be identified more easily on mobile? But why would this influence rankings?

Comment: @w3dk When you are using android, you are always logged in, Google can always identify you with default android setup. This can happen in desktop too, for example if you are logged in within chrome, but not by default. And when you are logged in, Google gives you personalized search result based on your profile, search history etc.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I think I was looking at it the wrong way round. So you're saying that the OP's own "personalization" is influencing their _perception_ of how well it is ranking?

Comment: Exactly. Say you favourited a business in Google+, (for relevant term) their pages are likely to rank better in SERP if Google identifies you and the Google+ user to be the same person. This can happen for topics as well. Say you like sports very much (from your profile, search history etc.). Now if you search for `bat` - `baseball bat`, `cricket bat` are likely to come up in the results, even though usually it should've been the flying animal, or if you are a tobacco person, perhaps the company BAT (British American Tobacco) will rank well compared to what it usually does for that search term